# Why the div's mess up on window scale down?

Tags: html, css

when I scale down the window for the following code, the div's dont scale down accordingly, instead they get cut. Can someone explain why? Please feel free to add more dummy text in the HTML section of div's "left , center, right" to give them more height.

As usual, I am focused more on the reason rather than any solution/alternative. Because I feel that identifying the reason (in my code) will help me learn and understand more deeply.

Code:

CSS:

```
<style>
html, body {
width: 100%;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
margin: 0px;
height: 100%;

}



.container {
width: 960px;
position: relative;
right: auto;
background-color: rgba(216,86,112,0.5);
height: 100%;
margin-top: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
}

.top {
width: 100%;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
background-color: rgba(204,51,0,1);
height: 10%;
position: relative;
margin: 0px;
text-align: center;
}

.left {
float: left;
height: auto;
width: 310px;
background-color: rgba(255,0,0,1);
margin-left: 5px;
margin-right: 5px;
position: relative;
}

.center {
float: left;
height: auto;
width: 310px;
background-color: rgba(0,255,0,1);
margin-left: 5px;
margin-right: 5px;
}

.right {
float: left;
height: auto;
width: 310px;
background-color: rgba(0,0,255,1);
margin-left: 5px;
margin-right: 5px;
}
</style>
```

HTML:

```
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

<div class="top">
</div>

<div class="left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
</div>

<div class="center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
</div>

<div class="right">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit               
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/fkwtaexz/show/) what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: yes, its one of the things I want to achieve. But also, i want the div's to scale down in proportion (both vertically and horizontally) while maintaining the aspect ratio instead of going down below each other when the window is scaled down (as for what you provided)

Comment: Okk..check whether [this](https://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/fkwtaexz/1/show/) is what you want..

Comment: Yes thats right. Now the only thing is that all of these div's are not aligned on the center of the page (as with my previous code)

Comment: check my answer @serious

Answer (score 0):

If you need to center the container in the middle and give it maximum width of 960 px than you should use this css:

```
.container {
display:block;
float:none;
width:100%;
max-width: 960px;
position: relative;
background-color: rgba(216,86,112,0.5);
height: 100%;
margin-top: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
}
```

Basically combination of float:none, margin:auto, width:100%, max-width:1000px or whatever you need and position relative will center your container. You can add clearfix to it if you will have inline-block elements inside it.

Comment: Thats perfect solution. But as I mentioned previously, I am interested in knowing as to how this happens rather than copy pasting the solution code. So in the above case, I noticed that you added [ width:100%
max-width: 960px; ] so what difference does it makes by simply just adding width:100% ?? Why using max width? what it does to center the container div?

Comment: It's kind of a css hack to center elements the same way as clearfix and some others. Combinations of the css rules I have written below the code are centering the elements. Max width will not allow the element to be more than 960px wide in pixels and 100% width and auto margin will spread the margin around equally.

Comment: ok, one more thing..... I tried adding margin-left and margin-right to 20% in the .container { } I was expecting a result so that the large pink container div (along with other inside div's) should leave 20px left and right margins. But after running the code, I noticed that the pink container div is shifted slightly towards the right. And when I scale down the window, the entire div shifts totally towards the right. Why is it so when both equal % margins are added to left and right?

Answer (score 0):

### See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/fkwtaexz/2/show/)

The reason why the `<div>`s were not scaling down was because you were hardcoding the width of each divs to a pixel value.

What I've done in my fiddle is that, I replaced all the hardcoded pixel values with its equivalent values in `%`.

The reason why I used `31%` for width is that because you have a total of 100% width and to fit 3 divs inside that, each div must be of `33.33%` width. But, you have `1%` margin left and right and thus the remaining `31.33%` is used as width.

Hope its clear for you..

**Updated CSS**

```
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  /* [disabled]left: 0px; */
  /* [disabled]top: 0px; */
  position: relative;
  right: auto;
  /* [disabled]bottom: auto; */
  background-color: rgba(216, 86, 112, 0.5);
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  /* [disabled]margin-bottom: auto; */
  margin-left: auto;
}

.top {
  width: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: rgba(204, 51, 0, 1);
  height: 10%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

.left {
  float: left;
  height: auto;
  width: 31.33%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
  margin-left: 1%;
  margin-right: 1%;
  position: relative;
}

.center {
  float: left;
  height: auto;
  width: 31.33%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 1);
  margin-left: 1%;
  margin-right: 1%;
}

.right {
  float: left;
  height: auto;
  width: 31.33%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 1);
  margin-left: 1%;
  margin-right: 1%;
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks! So does that means that in responsive designs, the % are preferred more than hard coding the size with px ?

Comment: No, that is not right completley..If you are using hardcoded pixel values, then you should write specific media css for each screen widths.. I would suggest you to take a look at bootstrap css to bulid responsive websites. Its very easy to understand and implement.

Comment: ok, one more thing..... I tried adding margin-left and margin-right to 20% in the .container { } I was expecting a result so that the large pink container div (along with other inside div's) should leave 20px left and right margins. But after running the code, I noticed that the pink container div is shifted slightly towards the right. And when I scale down the window, the entire div shifts totally towards the right. Why is it so when both equal % margins are added to left and right?

Comment: If you need just 20px margin, dont add 20%. Instead add something like 2% margin. Also, make sure that you reduce the width when you change the margins.

Comment: Hello thanks for your response again. Idecreased the margins to 2% and also reduced the width of the container div to 80%, 90% etc, but still the container div does not align symmetrically horizontally. Its stays shifted towards the left. However, when I increased the width of container to 100% and margin left/right to 2%, the container div had margin of 2% from the left but NO MARGIN on the right.The container div maintained that even on scaling. HOWEVER when I set the container width to AUTO then I am finally able to get even margins of 2px (left and right) even on scaling. Why is that so?